# confusion in intstalling winusb.sys in windows 7

Tags: usb, winusb

I'm trying to write an c++ code to turn off power-management option on the USB devices , i found that there are winusb api's to do the same .I downloaded the wdk and got the necessary files for the same . I went and saw the system32 folder and i could see the file winusb.sys already present(in Windows 7) ,so should i follow the steps as per the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/hardware/ff540283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to reinstall the driver by using an inf file and creating packages ? .

I went through the api's and the API's need the GUID of the winusb.sys to to initialize the winusb functions and to get the handle for the device ,given an winusb.sys how to find its guid ?

Comment: I found a way to install winusb , the project in this link http://winusbnet.codeplex.com/ has tools to install the winusb driver easily .The driver is installed and im getting error 10 .

Comment: what device are you trying to install winusb on?